# I2C_DR register wont be cleared

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, i2c, keil

I'm using stm32f103c8 and PCA9685 devices. I'm trying to send data to PCA9685 via I2C bus. I send data using I2C_DR register. But when i write a data to I2C_DR register it sticks to it. After the data is send thee I2C_DR register should be cleared but it wont happen in my code. I have no idea why this is happening. This is what i see in logic analyzer.

[image]

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

void I2C_Write_Single(int device_address, int mem_address, int data);
void I2C_Restart(int device_address, int data);

uint32_t temp = 0;

int main(){
/*********STEPS FOLLOWED*********
1. Enable the I2C Clock and GPIO Clock
2. Configure I2C Pins for alternate function
3. Reset I2C
4. Program the peripheral input clock in I2C_CR2 Register in order to generate correct timing
5. configure the clock control register
6. Configure the rise time register
7. Program the I2C_CR1 register to enable the peripheral
*/  
    
    I2C1->CR1 |= (1<<15);
    I2C1->CR1 &=~ (1<<15);  
    
    //GPIO Port B enabled
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<3);
    //I2C enabled
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C1EN;
    //timer enable TIM2 (general timer)
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM4EN;
    
    //TIM2 config
    TIM4->PSC |= 0;
    TIM4->ARR |= 71;
    TIM4->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;
    TIM4->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM4->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
    
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM4_IRQn);  
    
    //Mode register set for 50MHz (B7 and B6)
    GPIOB->CRL |= (1<<25) | (1<<24);
    GPIOB->CRL |= (1<<29) | (1<<28);
    //GPIO B7 and B6 pin registers (alternate function open drain) 
    GPIOB->CRL |= (1<<27) | (1<<26);
    GPIOB->CRL |= GPIO_CRL_CNF7_1 | (1<<30);    
    
    //Peripheral frequency (APB1) 36MHz (its written in datasheet)
    I2C1->CR2 |= 36 ;
    //I2C clock control register
    /* to calculate CCR (Clock Control Register) CCR= [((I2C_Period)/2)/(APB1_Period)] 
    I2C period is 400KHz(from user manual page 781) Ti2c= 1/100K = 10us
    APB1 Period = 1/36 = 27.7 ns
    CCR = [(5000ns)/(27.7ns)]= 180
    */
    I2C1->CCR |= 180;
    I2C1->TRISE |= 37 ; // TRise = CR2+1 (from datasheet page 783)
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_ACK;
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;    
    
    I2C_Restart(0x00, 0x06);    

    I2C_Write_Single( 0x80, 0x00, 0x08); //SLEEP bit gets cleared so we can get PWM signal
    
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x40, 0x00, 1<<6); //EXTERNAL CLOCK bit gets cleared so we can get PWM signal
     
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x40, 0xFE, 0XB0); // PRE_SCALE registers set to 0xB0 that way PWM Frequency will be 50 MHz (PCA9685 Datasheet page 9)
    
    // PWM delay %0 so LED0_ON_L and LED0_ON_H registers set to 0
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x40, 0x06, 0X01);
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x40, 0x07, 0X99); 
    
    // 1.5ms PWM will be given (1,5/20)*4096=307 LED0_OFF_H= 3 (decimal) LED0_OFF_H= 07 (decimal)
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x41, 0x09, 0X08);
    I2C_Write_Single( 0x41, 0x08, 0X00);    
    
    return 0;
}

void I2C_Write_Single(int device_address, int mem_address, int data)
{
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START; //generate start condition
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB)); // we check the SB flag if start bit didn't sent master device will stay in this loop

    I2C1->DR |= device_address  ; // device address is 0x00 
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR)); // we check ADDR flag. Once there is address mach device will exit the loop
    temp = I2C1->SR1 | I2C1->SR2; // we need to clear ADDR bit after we checked the flags. To reset SR1 and SR2 registers we just read them

    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE)); // wait for the byte transfer
    I2C1->DR |= mem_address  ; // MODE1 register (PCA9685 datasheet page 9)
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_BTF));//wait for transmit
    
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE)); // wait for the byte transfer
    I2C1->DR |= data << 1  ; // to set PWM frequency we set SLEEP bit 1 (PCA9685 datasheet page 24)
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_BTF));//wait for transmit
    
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP; //generate stop condition
}

void I2C_Restart(int device_address, int data)
{
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START; //generate start condition
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB)); // we check the SB flag if start bit didn't sent master device will stay in this loop

    I2C1->DR |= device_address; // device address is 0x00 
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR)); // we check ADDR flag. Once there is address mach device will exit the loop
    temp = I2C1->SR1 | I2C1->SR2; // we need to clear ADDR bit after we checked the flags. To reset SR1 and SR2 registers we just read them

    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE)); // wait for the byte transfer
    I2C1->DR |= data; // MODE1 register (PCA9685 datasheet page 9)
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_BTF));//wait for transmit
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE)); // wait for the byte transfer   
    
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP; //generate stop condition    
}
```

I tried to clear the register manually but when I write `I2C1->DR &=~ 0xFF`, master device immediately sends `0x00` data to the slave.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how I2C_DR works. It's not a variable in memory. It is used both for writing to and reading from an I2C bus and it behaves differently for writing and reading. And both operations have side effects. In your use case, you should not read from the register and not use operations like `|=` (combination of read and write). What is "cleared" supposed to be? Reading 0? You must not read I2C_DR except for retrieving a byte in a read transaction.

Comment: I'm trying to write data to slave address.

Comment: The main problem is `I2C1->DR |= ...`. Replace it with `I2C1->DR = ...`.

Comment: thank you so much it worked what should i do to learn more about this stuff?

Comment: Read, experiment, fail, and repeat until you understand.